# Add claims to a JWT token in OpenAM?

Tags: jwt, openid, openam

I’m using openAM access token end point to get a refresh token and id_token. But jti claim is missing in my id_token. How can I include this into id_token?

My id_token claims are as following,

```
{
“at_hash”: “kZVRzMbiEVbhH9cn1NlPTw”,
“sub”: “user1”,
“iss”: “http://openam.example.com:80/openam/oauth2”,
“tokenName”: “id_token”,
“aud”: [
“MyClientId”
],
“c_hash”: “mWLBu83Jg3Y1Kj6em3kQDQ”,
“org.forgerock.openidconnect.ops”: “bcf12880-a3f6-46d8-aad7-98250ab9a43f”,
“azp”: “MyClientId”,
“auth_time”: 1489831204,
“realm”: “/”,
“exp”: 1489834804,
“tokenType”: “JWTToken”,
“iat”: 1489831204
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you need to add openidconnect in services section inorder to get the id_token

Comment: Sorry if you want claims, customize the OIDC script, u can get and manipulate the script however u want